Cognito, How to confirm initial password reset on user sign up was successful using amazon-cognito-triggers
I am using cognito AuthFlow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH. When users sign up they are sent a temp password, when they login with the temp password they are prompted to change their password. I need a trigger or a way to confirm when this step was succesful.
It seems post_conf_handler is only triggered when the password is reset using the forgot password workflow, not at sign up and there is no challenge, such as NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED sent in the resp from post_auth_handler when the user logs in with the temp password.
Does anyone know how I can detect the password has initially been reset?
These are my intiate_auth params
response = client.initiate_auth(
                ClientId=SIGN_IN_POOL_ID,
                AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
                AuthParameters={
                    'USERNAME': SYSTEM_USERNAME,
                    'PASSWORD': SYSTEM_PASSWORD,
                }
            )

